# showing (0,1) with absolute value metric is not a complete metric space

Tags: real-analysis

According to the wikipedia, The open interval (0,1), with the absolute value metric, is not complete

But i could not find any proof for this one

Does anyone have any proof to show that (0,1) with absolute value metric is not a complete metric space?

Comment: $\{\frac1n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n=\frac{1}{n}\,,$ this is a cauchy sequence which doesn't converge.

Comment: so to prove we just say that {1/n} is a cauchy sequence which doesn't converge. {1/n} goes o not (0,1). like that?

Comment: Yeah basically, you might want to show that it is cauchy though.

Comment: lol easiest proof ever then

Comment: may i ask one more btw? how to prove that (0,1) with the discrete metric of (R,d)=R_d is a complete metric space,

Comment: i understnd the definition: any set X with the discrete metric is complete

Comment: You need to show that every cauchy sequence in a space with discrete metric converges. This is simple because if $d(x,y)<1$ then $x=y.$

Comment: could you show us how to prove?

Comment: Which part? That is most of the proof...